# Selenium no alert is active

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

They can help me with the following error, which happens when I try to close a window to print, in my pc it works correctly, but in another computer it fails.

with this line of code

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss ();
```

Error: OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 'No alert is active'

I am using Internet Explorer
Selenium c#
Nuget's of selenium 3.12.0

[ie window print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGniQ.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMKG9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium Alert is meant for javascript alert pop up. The print window is os related. It cannot be handled in selenium.

You can simulate keyboard events to close click print. 
You can use  [InputSimlator](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms) Nuget package

or [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library) library from codeproject.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information, I used the InputSimulator nuget package.
regards